# Partial Credit Retake

Tags: grading

I want to offer my students a chance to correct their exam problems (with explanation) for partial credit in lieu of a curve. I was thinking of the opportunity to get half of their points back. However, a 90% can only go up to 95%, whereas a 50% could become 75%. Is there a more fair way to offer exam correction?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's unfair about the scheme you propose?

Comment: I'm worried about a student who had an 16 turned into a 18 being jealous about his friend turning a 12 into an 16.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've never had students voice that complaint (anonymously or otherwise) when I've done the same "50% of your missed points back" scheme. And even if that were not the case, I don't think feelings of envy are a good enough reason to not help student demonstrate learning and growth.

Comment: I recommend doing exactly what you say you're going to do in your syllabus, unless it's to fix an unanticipated problem, especially if the problem is to correct an unfairness.

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this answer would help or if it is too late for this semester!

However, I just started a new retake approach that I learned from a colleague. I am now offering all of the students a chance to retake every exam. The retake is per question, so they retake only the questions that they did not do well in. I would only give them 80% of the difference they score. In order to be fair to those who are not retaking the test.
In order to demonstrate their mastery of the necessary method, students must successfully complete the question or questions they wish to retake in order to register for the retake!

I think this is helpful for the students because they will have the opportunity to study a certain topic again, ideally!! However, it is too much work (I would not recommend it for large classes).

Comment: how does this work? "In order to demonstrate their mastery of the necessary method, students must successfully complete the question or questions they wish to retake in order to register for the retake!" -- if they completed it why would they need to retake it?

Comment: Sorry, mastery may be the wrong word.
I indicate to the students that the retake involves the same topic. They have to demonstrate that they are able to solve it. So, they practice answering the question they failed (& want to retake).
I will review their approach and mistakes when they register. Sometimes they are unable to resolve it; hence, we review the concept.
I received positive feedback from engineering students. They felt this method helped them review a topic they didn't comprehend. After the exam, students usually ignore it because restudying it is pointless! (their own words)

Comment: It was the other clause I was asking about, not the "mastery" one

Comment: I think that homework assignments are just give-aways for students (at least in STEM). So in order to make them restudy the topic, I give them the option to retake it.
The other benefit is that no one is asking for a curve to push up the grade; the retake is the curve!

Comment: Resolving the questions (which they want to retake) on their own time is like an uncredited homework assignment for that particular topic!

Answer (score -1):

I used to use a more generous option to all students on exercises, but not for exams, though exams were only a small(ish) part of the overall grade. If you announce such a policy at the beginning of the course it is best, though you need to be careful that you don't encourage people to slack on the first "taking", expecting to make it up later. Not allowing "full marks" on a retake helps encourage better behavior on the first take, I find.

As long as you don't disadvantage others, such as those who don't need such an option, you should have no ethical considerations.

If you aren't tenured, I'd chat with this with your department chair before instituting it, however.

But a focus on learning, which repetition helps, is better than a focus on grading. If they can show they have learned then I never had any problem with being generous with points. Just don't disadvantage anyone.

Again, they are there to learn, not to "beat" others, though not everyone will agree.